# Unlock time clarity

Tags: transaction-unlock-time, coinbase-transaction

In Monero transactions can be locked for a period of blocks or until a certain UNIX time. All the outputs of a transaction are locked together. All coinbase/miner transactions are locked for exactly 60 blocks (as of protocol v12). It seems clear that an output from a transaction with UNIX lock time can be spent in a block with timestamp greater than or equal to the UNIX lock time.

Question: is the unlock block height the first block that an output is spendable, or the last block it is unspendable? E.g. block 1 published, coinbase unlock_time is block 61 (current block + 60), can the coinbase be spent in block 61 or must it be at least block 62?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question: is the unlock block height the first block that an output is spendable, or the last block it is unspendable? ... can the coinbase be spent in block 61 or must it be at least block 62?

61.