# How many blocks must miners wait before spending the block subsidy?

Tags: block-reward, transaction-unlock-time, coinbase-transaction

After a block is mined, how long is the block subsidy locked from being spent?

Comment: [This previous question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11911/unlock-time-clarity) has the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find that when searching for these keywords.  Also wanted to put a reference to the actual constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Coinbase can be spent *after* 60 blocks.

See
[`CRYPTONOTE_MINED_MONEY_UNLOCK_WINDOW`](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/e49a055e89b2d335da34250d2793698804c50df2/src/cryptonote_config.h#L44)